# Is it possible to change the cursor while dragging using HTML drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

Í'm trying to make my application look a little better, and something that has been bothering me is the cursor while dragging using HTML drag and drop.

I have tried searching stackoverflow and google but the only posts I can see are pretty old or don't have an answer. By default it looks like the image below. I'd like to change it to the grabbing cursor.

[Default dragging cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELran.png)

Any ideas? Thanks for any replies :)

Comment: You Can use use cursor:grab and grabbing